# Compile static tmux with libutempter support

Tags: compiling, tmux

I'd like to fix issue for tmux when it can't report username via `logname`:

```
logname: no login name
```

I'm using steps below:

```
# lets assume all other prerequisites are compiled already
# and staged/installed to $HOME/opt

# libutempter (http://freecode.com/projects/libutempter)
# URL : ftp://ftp.altlinux.org/pub/people/ldv/utempter/libutempter-1.1.5.tar.bz2
tar xvfj libutempter-1.1.5.tar.bz2
cd libutempter-1.1.5
vi Makefile
grep 'DESTDIR =' Makefile
---
DESTDIR = /home/xxxxxx/opt

make
make install

# tmux (http://tmux.sourceforge.net/)
# URL : git://git.code.sf.net/p/tmux/tmux-code
git clone git://git.code.sf.net/p/tmux/tmux-code tmux
cd tmux
sh autogen.sh

CFLAGS="-I$HOME/opt/include -I$HOME/opt/usr/include -I$HOME/opt/include/ncurses" \
CPPFLAGS="-I$HOME/opt/include -I$HOME/opt/usr/include -I$HOME/opt/include/ncurses" \
LDFLAGS="-L$HOME/opt/lib -L$HOME/opt/include/ncurses -L$HOME/opt/include -L$HOME/opt/usr/lib" \
./configure --enable-static

CPPFLAGS="-I$HOME/opt/include -I$HOME/opt/usr/include -I$HOME/opt/include/ncurses" \
LDFLAGS="-static -L$HOME/opt/include -L$HOME/opt/usr/include -L$HOME/opt/include/ncurses -L$HOME/opt/lib -L$HOME/opt/usr/lib" \
make
```

But tmux still can't report login name via `logname`.

I can't install packages (no root access).

I updated env vars and flags, ldd reports no shared libs, but tmux still can't show login name via logname.

Answer (score 2):

This is the intended purpose of `libutempter`, but it also requires a level of application support, which `tmux` has [only recently (Feb 2014)](http://sourceforge.net/p/tmux/mailman/message/32021471/) gotten in the *master* branch (which you are using), but might not be ready for use.

From the FAQ in the current  1.9a source distribution:

```
* How is tmux different from GNU screen?
  [...]
  - screen has support for updating utmp. Nobody has really come up with a clean,
    portable way to do this without making tmux setuid or setgid yet.
```

The master branch [online FAQ](http://sourceforge.net/p/tmux/tmux-code/ci/master/tree/FAQ)  omits exactly that point, though the `CHANGES` file is not yet updated.

Check for the define `HAVE_UTEMPTER` in `Makefile` (not the expected `config.h`!) after running `configure`, if it's not defined then you need to read `config.log` to determine what's wrong with the build environment.

My best guesses at this time are:

- you don't have a `libutempter.a`, only `libutempter.so`, so the use of `-static` causes libutempter to fail detection, since it cannot be linked
- it is detected and compiled in, but the `utempter` helper (to which the privileged task of updating `utmp` is delegated) is not setgid (usually setgid utmp)
- some systems are [known to limit access](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=246063) to that helper to [prevent silliness](http://packetstormsecurity.com/files/117176/Utempter-Fake-Entry-Manipulation.html), so  the invoking binary (i.e. `tmux`) must *also* be setgid (usually setgid utempter)

If you build `libutempter` yourself it should make *both* static and dynamic versions, but I suspect that distribution packages will only contain the dynamic version.

If you do not have root access, you *cannot* install your own libutempter correctly:  it cannot maintain the system `utmp`/`wtmp` files. If there is a system install of libutempter that lacks only `libutempter.a`, then you should be able to compile your own `libutempter.a` in order configure/link `tmux` statically, and use the already installed system setgid helper (usually `/usr/lib/utempter/utempter` or `/usr/libexec/utempter/utempter`). You cannot workaround the problem if access to that binary is also restricted, i.e. `tmux` needs to be setgid to run it.

Error handling for the new libutempter features is incomplete in `tmux` at this time, if you can rebuild libutempter with `-DUTEMPTER_DEBUG` it might help if none of the above did:

```
make CFLAGS=-DUTEMPTER_DEBUG
```

Comment: Thank you for answer.

I've played with code a little, and think that utemper is used by tmux. Will probably need to check `-DUTEMPTER_DEBUG`.

Comment: BTW, how can i recompile libutemper with debug?

Comment: This should do the trick `make CFLAGS=-DUTEMPTER_DEBUG`